# Limit of function with Cosinus

Tags: real-analysis, limits

again I have a question to finding the limit.

Given is $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1-\cos(x-y)}{x-y}$.
I tried:

- set $(x-y) = 2r$
- then $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1-\cos(2r)}{2r} = \dfrac{\sin^2(r)}{r}$

However, I'm not sure what to do next. Maybe you can tell me if my first step was good or which way you'd prefer more.

What I am looking for is the limit for (x,y) -> (0,0).

Comment: What is the limit you're trying to find?

Comment: What you did is correct but are you trying to find the limit for x -> y ?

Comment: I'm sorry: It's (x,y) -> (0,0)

Comment: Well, $\lim f(x, y) = \lim f(r) = 0$. Which equality do you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your idea:

$$2r:=x-y\;,\;\;\text{so that}\;\; (x,y)\to(0,0)\implies r\to 0$$

and then

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\sin^2r}r=\lim_{r\to 0}\sin r\cdot\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\sin r}r=0\cdot 1=0$$